# NodeJS - Having trouble reloading external js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to build a sort of plugin manager that can reload external source files on the fly without actually shutting down the node app. Just as a quick proof of concept is just eval'd my plugin files that simply are just functions being prototyped to a class. Everything seemed to work great, except that I cant seem to get the scoping right. The functions get evaluated and prototyped, but im not sure why the functions cant grab global vars. Does anyone have any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than manually loading the file, you could just rely on `require`.

Now, the only problem is that require has an internal cache and will only load modules once. However, you can force it to unload with this quick workaround:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve(myPlugin)];
require(myPlugin);
```

Comment: What would be the best way to get these functions into my Class itself by chance?

Comment: I made a quick loop that loads all of my plugins, but they still cant see things in global scope, like the fs module, etc.